# How to install LAMP server in Ubuntu 16.04 and add www document root to user's home?

Tags: server, apache2, php, home-directory, lamp

How to install LAMP server in Ubuntu 16.04 and add www document root to user's home

Answer (score 0):

#### Install LAMP server:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

#### Enable `userdir` module:

> sudo a2enmod userdir

#### Enable PHP execution in user directory:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.conf

(if you use PHP5, it's php5.conf)

Comment this part:

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save

#### Enable directory listing:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Add this:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save

---

Restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Now put your php files in **/home/yourname/public_html** directory and go to
 http://localhost/~yourname from your web browser.